# Missing ws2def.h, from which package can I download?

Tags: c++, mingw, poco-libraries

I'm trying to compile a C++ project on Win10 Pro with Eclipse, MinGW and the POCO library.
A POCO header include ws2def.h that is missing on my Laptop.
From which package/library/website can I find this missing file ?
MinGW seems not to install it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a POCO header. It is a [Win32 API header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2def/). MinGW seems to have [its own version](https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/include/ws2def.h) of it.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, with your link to MinGW, I was able to download the right version of many other found on the net.